# Vuejs : How to not a boolean value in V-model?

Tags: vue.js, v-model

I am getting value of `options.customerdata.showbutton` as `true` from an API, so now the switch is in on condition.

I want the switch to be in off, hence `v-model="false"` should be given. But
 tried giving

```js
v-model="!(options.customerdata.showbutton)"
```

does not work and shows error. How to achieve this?

```
<b-form-checkbox v-model="options.customerdata.showbutton" name="logo-display" switch >
</b-form-checkbox>
```

Comment: Can you show us the error?

Comment: [vue/valid-v-model]
'v-model' directives require the attribute value which is valid as LHS.eslint-plugin-vue

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Model can't be expression (it must be reference to data/property)

Easiest way is define data and set it with negated value. But be aware that in this case your model is not change when customerdata is changed after component initialization.

```
data: {
  return {
    show: !this.options.customerdata.showbutton
  } 
}
```

If you need to store value back to options (or bound value to customerdata), you can use also computed property with setter/getter

```
computed {
  show: {
    get () {
      !this.options.customerdata.showbutton
    }

    set (value) {
      this.options.customerdata.showbutton = !value
    }
  }
}
```

For both case your bind it with

```
v-model="show"
```

Comment: So i should store options.customerdata.showbutton in a var and negate it and bind it in the v-model ?

Comment: @JithinB I also added example with setter if you want to modify customerdata back

Comment: @JithinB So answer is it depends on you usecase (I don't know what you are doing with checkbox value) and if you need to propagate it back, Anyway, these two proposals should cover common scenarios.

Comment: The first part is working fine, But storing the value back is not working ! If i turn the switch on ( false to true ) and refresh it. Its again showing as fasle !

Comment: @JithinB it working in terms that options.customerdata is update. But nobody persist change to see it after reload. That's completely different story. (For it you obviously need to trigger API call on change)

Comment: The only thing i changed from your code was , you declared the variable show in data ( as i have dont have options at the time declaring ) , i gave a default value true and  changes the value once i get the options json by this,show = options.customerdata.showbutton

Comment: Is there a way can use something instead of v-model ? like v-bind ?